# Quantum vs Classical solution to the Gibbs Paradox

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, bosons

The thermodynamic probability of a gas
with distinguishable particles having spin-$0$ is given by the expression:-

$Ω_{MB} = N!~Π_i\frac{g_i^{n_i}}{n_i!}$

If the particles were indistinguishable, the thermodynamic probability will be given by the expression:-

$Ω = Π_i\frac{g_i^{n_i}}{n_i!}$

This is the classical solution.

The quantum solution is using other statistics like BE or FD.

In this case, since the particles have integer spin, we must use the BE.

Then, the thermodynamic probability is:-

$Ω_{BE} = \frac{(n_i + g_i - 1)!}{n!(g_i - 1)!}$

Which of the solution is correct?
Are, the two different expressions equivalent?

The classical expression is used to find the values of the coefficients $α$ and $β$ in the distribution laws. If the classical expression is incorrect/inaccurate then the derivation must also be wrong. Then, why those values are accepted?

Comment: You already know that a spin zero gas is bosonic, why are you even asking this question? Classical anything are only approximations to our quantum reality, so when faced with that choice, it is clear which one will be a better description.